# Create page from dynamic link from a static file in Nextjs

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I have a static file with my array of object from which I create dynamics link.
The link is created, but I can't display my page because I haven't the props from the link

```
import { useState, useEffect, useMemo } from "react";
import dynamic from 'next/dynamic';
import Link from "next/link";
import Head from "next/head";
import KeyboardDoubleArrowUpIcon from '@mui/icons-material/KeyboardDoubleArrowUp';
const Post = dynamic(() => import('../../components/Post'), {
  loading: () => <div>Loading...</div>
})
const ROUTE_POST_ID = "posts/[id]";

import styles from '../../styles/global.module.scss';
  
const Posts = () => {
  const blogPosts = [
   {
      title: "blabla",
      subTitle: "toto ",
      body: `
the text of my body
      `,
      id: 1
    },{
      title: "blabla",
      subTitle: "toto ",
      body: `
the text of my body
      `,
      id: 2
    },
    {
      title: "blabla",
      subTitle: "toto ",
      body: `
the text of my body
      `,
     id: 3
    },
    {
      title: "blabla",
      subTitle: "toto ",
      body: `
the text of my body
      `,
     id:4
    }
  ];
  
  const blogItems = Object.values(blogPosts).map((val, id) => { return (val.category); });
  const [item, setItem] = useState(blogItems);
  const [selectedCategory, setSelectedCategory] = useState("");

  useEffect(() => {
    setItem(blogPosts);
  }, []);
  
  function handleCategoryChange(event) {
    setSelectedCategory(event.target.value);
  }

  function getFilteredList() {
  if (!selectedCategory) {
    return blogPosts;
  }
  return blogPosts.filter((item) => item.category === selectedCategory);
}
const filteredList = useMemo(getFilteredList, [selectedCategory, blogPosts]);
 
  return (
    <div className={styles.styleblog}>
      <div className={ styles.filterContainer }>
        <p>Filtrer par categorie :</p>
        <p className={ styles.selectContainer }>
            <select
              name="category-list"
              id="category-list"
              onChange={handleCategoryChange}
            >
              <option value="">Toutes</option>
              <option value="cat1">cat1</option>
                <option value="cat2">Cat2</option>
                <option value="ca3">cat2</option>
            </select>
        </p>
      </div>
        <div className={ styles.postsContainer }>
            <div className={styles.blogContainer}>
          {/* { filteredList.map((post, index) => (
              <Post key={"post-"+ index} index={index} post={post} />
            )
          ) } */}
          { filteredList.map((post, index) => {
              return (
        <div key={`post-${post.id}`}>
          <Link
            href={{
                      pathname: "blog/" + encodeURIComponent(post.title),
              post: { post }
                    } }
                    as={`blog/${encodeURIComponent(post.title)}`}
          >
            <a>{post.title}</a>
          </Link>
                </div>
                )
})}
          </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
  
export default Posts;

 export async function getStaticProps(context) {
   return {
     props: blogPosts, // will be passed to the page component as props
   }
 }
```

It's create links just as I want.
But I can't manage to create dynamically this pages, I tried

```
const Post = (props) => {
console.log(props.pageProps)
  // const { title, subTitle, body, category } = props;
  // const firstSentenceJoined = body.split(' ').slice(0, 30).join(' ');
  // const firstSentence = firstSentenceJoined + "...";
  return (
    <></>
    // <div className={ styles.postContainer } key={ "post-" + post.index } post={post}>
    //   <h1 className={ styles.heading }>{ title }</h1>
    //   { subTitle &&
    //     <h2 className={ styles.heading2 }>
    //       { subTitle }
    //     </h2>
    //   }
    //   <div className={ styles.blogBody }>
    //     <p className={ styles.blogText }>
    //       { stringToBreakpointedHtml(firstSentence) }
    //     </p>
    //   </div>
    //   <div className={ styles.info }>
    //     <span className={ styles.blogSpan }> Catégorie: { category }</span> <br />
    //   </div>
    // </div>
  );
}
export async function getServerSideProps({ params }) {
  return {
    props: params
  }
}
```

But in the props console I just have the title.
I don't understand how it works...
Thanks for helping me

Comment: I think you are doing it wrong. Please read https://nextjs.org/learn/basics/dynamic-routes.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but this is for blog with mdx, and I don't use this..

Comment: It shows how to create dynamic pages, and that's what you want to do. I would give it a try if I were you.

Comment: Yes I tried but don't understand how to do in my case..

Comment: I think I'll try to do it with router because I can't find how to do it

Comment: _"in the props console I just have the title"_ - You only have the title because that's what you pass in the dynamic route parameter: `pathname: "blog/" + encodeURIComponent(post.title)`. You can't pass props data through `Link`. Instead, you need to retrieve the data for the post inside `getServerSideProps` based on the param you pass in the route.